# QT 5.0 QDebug compilation error

Tags: qt5

I am having trouble compiling my code with QDebug, but i really need it.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QDebug() << "hello";
    return a.exec();
}
```

This is an example of the error i got on this simple test: 
no matching function for call to 'QDebug::QDebug()'

Comment: use `qDebug()` instead of `QDebug()`

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
qDebug() << "hello";
```

Comment: Strangely enough I have sources with qDebug() << "hello"; and it doesnt compile. The message is "no matching call to QMessageLogger::debug().

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that QDebug does not have a default constructor. `QDebug() << "hello";` would work if it did have one.

These are the available constructors:

```
QDebug(QIODevice* device);
QDebug(QString* string);
QDebug(QtMsgType type);
// and the copy constructor of course.
```

duDE's answer gives you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For version 5.15 of Qt following worked for me,

add include file,

```
#include <QDebug>
```

and use,

```
qDebug() << "Your debug message.";
```